# Refreshing mysql query on checkbox check

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a control panel in php and mysql that displays on page load. I have a checkbox on that page(default off, not stored in db or tied to anything other than being an option to show old items), that when i click it, i want the query to refresh the data with the new filter applied. Basically on load it show only active items, when they check the checkbox i want the page to reload showing outdated items.

My code is:

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="true">
    </form>
    <?PHP

    $showold = (isset($_REQUEST['filter']));
    if ($showold === 'checked' )  
    {
        $showold = "WHERE `MyTable` = '0'";
    }
    else
    {
        $showold = "WHERE `MyTable` = '1'";
    }
            $query_NowPouring = "SELECT * FROM MyTable $showold";
            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_NowPouring);

    if($result){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        #set variables here and display the info in table here.
             }
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: It'd probably be better to use the `GET` method instead as you're not actually changing anything

Comment: I dont't thing that the line `if ($showold === 'checked' )` is working as you expected. The return value of isset() is a bool which indicates if the variable is exists or not. You can't compare this with a string.

Comment: Benjamin, your prob right as i just tossed that in there for proof of concept.

Comment: Why the down vote with no explanation? Please tell me how to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

Your code (isset($_REQUEST['filter'])); is returning boolean like 0 or 1 not string and you are matching it with string at if ($showold === 'checked' ) .

Problem is you can not compare boolean with string.

Comment: I just put that there as an example of what my filter is doing.

Comment: your filter will not work. you first use isset function to check filter parameter is there or not. After then you again get parameter filter value and compare that value in if condition